# Content Hub sending too many messages to Service Bus

Tags: content-hub, azure-service-bus

We have just upgraded to SC10 and our Content Hub seems to be filling up our Service Bus queue with unwanted messages and overloading the queue. The top 10 messages are all saying it has updated the `ContentHubTriggerSync`

Here is the message. Has anyone had this issue or similar? We have 90K messages in the queue and the service bus is only running about 5 a min. Thanks for the help.

```
"PropertyChanges": [
        {
          "Culture": "(Default)",
          "Property": "ContentHubTriggerSync",
          "Type": "System.String",
          "OriginalValue": "07/12/2023 5:22:51 AM",
          "NewValue": "07/14/2023 5:22:14 PM"
        }
```